# How to deploy string variable of solidly code in hardhat

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ethers.js, hardhat

In order to deploy a contract, we fetch the smart contract file with hardhat and then deploy it:

```
const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy();
```

I was wondering how I could assign a string of solidity smart contract code to the variable and then deploy it, with no need to create a separate file for smart contract.

Comment: You need to get hold of that contract's bytecode. Passing the original source code would be a pain in the ass.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I just need to compose the smart contract code in js based on the user's preferences and assign this smart contract code to the variable. When I already have the variable with code, what could I do next to deploy it? How can I get its bytecode as you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Using hardhat it should take care of compiling the source code to the contract's byte code for you as long as you use the hre object and the contracts name. Just make sure you have your solidity code in the contracts folder. When running your script try using:

```
const tokenContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
const tokenContract = await Token.deploy();
await tokenContract.deployed();
*insert functions you want to run on the deployed contract here*
```

To run the script via terminal use:

```
npx hardhat run <script_path>
```